# Llamar a un argumento específico con nombre en JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

En JavaScript, dada una función con múltiples argumentos con nombre, ¿es posible dar valor a sólo alguno de estos, independientemente del orden?

Pongo un ejemplo. Situemos la función:

```
function foo(a=true, b=true, c=true, d=true, e=true, f=true){
    ...
}
```

Ahora yo quiero llamar a la función con c y f a false, pero me interesa dejar el resto de valores intactos. Para ello, conozco dos formas 'oficiales'.

La primera, más fea, es ponerlo todo a mano:

```
foo(true, true, false, true, true, false);
```

La otra, es aprovechar que las variables no definidas se evaluan por defecto:

```
foo(undefined, undefined, false, undefined, undefined, false);
```

Pero mi pregunta es si, al igual que en, por ejemplo Python, se pueden establecer directamente los parámetros por nombre de alguna forma, como por ejemplo así:

```
foo(c=false, d=false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es realizar [asignación por destructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Lo que harías sería pasar un objeto con los elementos que quieres modificar en lugar de pasar las variables directamente a la función. Entonces por la destructuración se asignarán sólo los valores que sean especificados.

Algo como esto:

```js
function foo({a=true, b=true, c=true, d=true, e=true, f=true} = {}){
  console.log(a, b, c, d, e, f);
}

foo({c:false, d:false});
```

Comment: ¿Hay que especificar siempre el uso de foo con un json, no?

Comment: En este caso, sí. No es exactamente igual a lo que tienes. Igual usando la sintaxis spread. Voy a hacer alguna prueba.

Comment: cambiando el orden al llamar `foo({d:false, c:false});` lo hace mas evidente =)